# Margin around invoice in letter

Tags: margins, scrlttr2, invoice

I'm using `pdflatex` to generate invoices with a `scrlttr2` document and an invoice inside that.

Most of the descriptions inside the invoice are quite long so I would like to remove the margin around the invoice table. I cannot find how to remove the margin in the cpan invoice documentation. Is this possible at all?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,enlargefirstpage,parskip=half,pagenumber=no,DIV=15,firstfoot=false,fromalign=right]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{invoice}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Martijn}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hoofdweg 322 \\ 9421XD  Smilde}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Somebody \\ Street \\ 9421KB Smilde}
\KOMAoptions{fromphone=false,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{Factuurnummer. 1}
\setkomavar{location}[description ]{\raggedleft Blabla\\KvK\\50433832 te Smilde\\IBAN\\Site\\emailaddress}
\opening{}
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{21}
\ProjectTitle{Vette opdracht}%
\Fee{Pizza halen} {67.00} {2.00}
\Fee{Appje bouwen} {67.00} {1.00}
\EBCi{Toeslag} {1}

\end{invoice}
\closing{Betalen binnen 14 dagen}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). If you are talking about the vertical spacing, you can issue something like `\vspace*{-50pt}` before the `invoice` environment and `\vspace*{-20pt}` after it.

Comment: Its the horisontal spacing. the table has the same huge margins horisontaly as the text in a standard letter. I need the table to have a margin of 1cm on both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the width of the invoice is hardcoded. Line 229 of the file invoice.sty says:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}lrrr}%
```

You could take invoice.sty, rename and change it. And then you could define a new columntype "I" and redefine it in your invoice file. Don't forget to change the package name in the preamble accordingly.

As soon as you change this, you can do whatever you wish with the margins. I'd suggest to put the invoice environment inside an addmargin environment (see the manual of KOMA-script).